# Mongo DB already findOne method giving wired result

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to create a new user in mongodb and looking for `existing user` but even if a am sending request with new user details it is still showing that `User alreadyExists`

```
export const signUp = async (req, res) => {
  const {email, password, username, roomid} = req.body;
  try {
    console.log(req.body);
    let existingUser = User.findOne({email});
    console.log(existingUser);
    if (existingUser) res.status(400).json({message: 'User already exists!!'});

    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

    const result = await User.create({
      email,
      password: hashedPassword,
      username,
      roomid,
    });

    const token = jwt.sign(
      {email: existingUser.email, id: existingUser._id},
      'test',
      {expiresIn: '1hr'}
    );
    res.status(201).json({result, token});
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Help Please

Someone just solve the problem of new user creation

Comment: what does it log at `console.log(existingUser)`? And I suppose you would like to exit from this handler, if a user already exists? Then you should do `return res.status(400)`. Otherwise your code will continue and try to create that existing user again ...

Comment: on `console.log(existingUser)`  it is logging a object which is actually true in the condition `if(existingUser)` and new data also getting blocked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line, because even after this line the program continues to run.

```
if (existingUser) res.status(400).json({message: 'User already exists!!'});
```

To:

```
if (existingUser) return res.status(400).json({message: 'User already exists!!'});
```

You need to `return` key.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const existingUser = db.collection('users').findOne({ email: email }); 

if (existingUser) { 
  res.json({ 
    message: 'User already exists', 
    existingUser: existingUser 
  }); 
  client.close(); 
  return; <-- stop executing code if user already exists 
} //checks if user already exists
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the code with the Else method so:

```
export const signUp = async (req, res) => {
  const {email, password, username, roomid} = req.body;
  try {
    
    console.log(req.body);
    
    let existingUser = User.findOne({email});
    
    console.log(existingUser);
    
    if (existingUser){
        return res.status(400).json({message: 'User already exists!!'});

    }else{
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

      const result = await User.create({
        email,
        password: hashedPassword,
        username,
        roomid,
      });
  
      const token = jwt.sign(
        {email: existingUser.email, id: existingUser._id},
        'test',
        {expiresIn: '1hr'}
      );
      return res.status(201).json({result, token});
    }


  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Note: Don't forget to turn the server off and then on again.